# Is there a way in Groovy to collect all Objects in a List for which a member variable matches a value in another List?

Tags: groovy

I have a List of Objects say `List<Family>` families.

I have another List of Strings with FamilyNames say `List<String>` names.

I want the most optimum way to get a List of all Families for which the FamilyNames matches that of names.

eg: Let's say I have 5 families. 1 through 5. with names Fam1,Fam2....Fam5
And `names = ["Fam1", "Fam2"]`

How can I get a List of Families back containing Fam1 & Fam2 ?

What if I want to match 2 params instead of 1.

I am trying to see if there is a way for doing this without iterating through the entire list and by calling any Groovy api?

Comment: If you want to find all, you have to iterate the whole list of families - how else would you know you got them all. And what is your definition of "Groovy API", that we are not allowed to use.  Is this homework? And please also add, what you have tried already (source and errors you get) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I come from the world of java. Just getting to use groovy syntax. There are a lot of shortcuts to doing things like these. I was looking for something in the order of ```families.findAll { it -> it.name in  names}```

Comment: "please also add, what you have tried already (source and errors you get) so we can improve on it." I am not trying to get a solution to the problem. I already mentioned what my approach will be to solve this (iteration). All I was looking for is a Groovy "trick" of doing this in fewer lines of code.

Comment: And what is your definition of "Groovy API" -> Something like "findAll"

Comment: What is the gain of using a groovy and then prevent the use of functions that are there for the last decode or so?  Or rather: what is the reasoing behind this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

> I want the most optimum way to get a List of all Families for which
>   the FamilyNames matches that of names.

It is difficult to say what is optimum because you could optimize for different things (fastest runtime, least memory, least code, most idiomatic, etc...)

You haven't indicated what JDK you are using so it isn't clear if you are open to using streams or not.

One approach that is very straightforward Groovy:

```
class Family {
    String name
}

List<Family> families = []
families << new Family(name: 'Fam1')
families << new Family(name: 'Fam2')
families << new Family(name: 'Fam4')
families << new Family(name: 'Fam5')

List names = ['Fam1', 'Fam2', 'Fam3']

List results = names.findAll { name ->
    families.find { family ->
        family.name == name
    }
}

// results will be  [Fam1, Fam2]
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. By optimum I was aiming for least number of lines of code.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Family {
    String name
}

List<Family> families = []
families << new Family(name: 'Fam1')
families << new Family(name: 'Fam2')
families << new Family(name: 'Fam4')
families << new Family(name: 'Fam5')

List names = ['Fam1', 'Fam2', 'Fam3']`enter code here`

families.findAll { it -> it.name in names}
```

Comment: The original question includes "How can I get a List back containing Fam1 & Fam2 ?".  Your solution of `families.findAll { it -> it.name in names}` is going to return a collection of `Family`, not a collection of names.

Comment: A Set is more efficient to check containment.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, I have rephrased my question. I was trying to get a list of Families.

Comment: "A Set is more efficient to check containment." - @cfrick That is true, but the question was explicit about wanting to use a `List`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown "the question was explicit about wanting to use a List" - for `names`.

Comment: @cfrick  "I have a List of Objects say List<Family> families."

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, but OP is using a `List names` for a containment check in the `findAll`.  A `Set` and then `contains` check is more efficient.

Comment: I agree that a `Set` is more efficient for lookups.